# open existing documents from server or local computer?

Tags: office-js

I am working on MAC. I am doing a word addin (javascript API)using office -js.(server is node)
Is there any way to open documents from server or from local computer.
Please help me regarding this issue.

open existing documents from server or local computer?? (using office-js API)

Thanks.